# User interface Mathematica 12.1 terribly slow

Tags: front-end, dataset, user-interface, version-12.1

I installed Mathematica 12.1 a few days ago and now I experience a serious speed slow down. When working with datasets for example Mathematica is close to be unusable. Even in the help systems it lasts more than a second until a reactions comes. Also scrolling through a dataset is nearly impossible, even for small datasets (460 x 53).

Is here anyone with similar problems and  can help me out. For the moment I changed back to 12.0 which is much more performant.

I use a MacMini with 6 cores, 64GB of Ram and 2 TB SSD, actual MacOS

Comment: Well, I am afraid nobody other than support can help you with this. My bet is that somebody overdid the the thing about fancy dynamic interaction with `Dataset`s...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: this is exactly what I have in mind. All the "bling bling" with headers and formatting within a dataset is nice, but only when I can do my work ;-)

Comment: For what it's worth, I have had some issues with display/scrolling of Dataset on my Linux 12.1. Not debilitating, but the Datasets were smaller than what is noted here.

Comment: Also, which specific Mac OS is being used? This information could be useful for diagnosis at our end.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I thought this bug was very well known internally, at least several of us beta testers complained before release ... Please do make a 12.1.1 which corrects this. Just playing with Wolfram's version of the epidemic data, a relatively tiny dataset, is very painful (while 12.0 works fine)

Comment: Is there a specific help page that exhibits this slowdown?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau As I said the actual MacOS 10.15.3

Comment: Crippling slowdown on Linux 64 bit as well, both example `Dataset`s.

Comment: (Earlier, I had commented saying I didn't see this behaviour. I was very wrong. I see this just the same as everyone else)

Comment: I gave this to Wolfram support, so let's wait and see for 12.1.1.

Comment: Where did you state it was 10.15.3? (I'm not claiming you didn't, I'm saying I do not see it and possibly the end of your post was truncated.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: You are absolutely right I wrote only "actual MacOS" which is 10.15.3 - it would have been better to write it down directly.

Comment: @mgamer in English, I think the word you meant was "current" rather than "actual". This is more confusing as the rest of your post makes you sound like a native English speaker.

Comment: @mikado: Thanks for this advice, my name "Gamer" sounds like native English of American - but nope I'm German, doing a lot of my work in the English language -  but never be perfect ;-)

Comment: The frontend slowdown is not only limited to Dataset issues. It also hangs for crowded plots. Windows 10 version here. Unusable for me a.t.m.

Comment: Same slowdown happens when I plot 3D histograms in my case. In general 3D graphs.

Comment: Any updates on this from WRI?

Comment: @M.R.Up to now (2020-03-31) not. On 2020-03-25 I got a mail from WolframTechnical Support that the issue has been reported to the developers. I'm still using 12.0

Answer (score 40):

### Official Statement

In case some of you missed it: There was an official reply from one of the WRI devs [recently in our chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53877071#53877071)

> Hi. This is Jose, from Wolfram. We are aware of an unacceptable slowdown in some Dataset expressions, due to a bad dynamic interaction with the summary boxes of some objects. Both the TimeSeries objects of the coronavirus datasets and the InterpolatingFunction objects in the example given before typeset via summary boxes. We are working on a solution and will release it as soon as it is available.

At this point, Szabolcs answered

> Thanks for the update. The example I posted does not have any summary boxes though, and it still makes the FE quite literally unusable. `Import["https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/ecdc/total_cases.csv", "Dataset", HeaderLines -> 1]`

and the reply was

> Many thanks for this example, @Szabolcs. We are looking into it too, and hope to have a fix very soon. We are improving Dataset in multiple ways, and WL 12.1 has focused on increased interactivity, Grid-like styling capabilities, storage of data in place, copy-paste, and other FrontEnd-related things. Summary boxes and similar typesetting constructs are important to identify and understand expressions, but they should not make the system much slower, of course.

Let's hope for the best.

### Original Answer

Not an official answer nor a solution. Just some insight. I reported this issue about 4 months ago for the pre-release because I experienced considerable slowdowns when working with things that are "nicely rendered" in the front end. This includes dates, time-series, interpolating functions, etc. The issue is particularly noticeable when you have a data-set (in itself a formatted table with dynamic stuff) that contains things like `TimeSeries`.

My go-to example is

```
res = ResourceData["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"]
```

This displays 20 rows and 7 columns and breaks my Linux and macOS front end. At home I have a Intel i7 Extreme with 8 cores (32GB RAM) and my macOS is running on the latest iMac Pro with 32GB RAM and the largest CPU available.

In particular, I saw the following issues:

- hovering the header entries so that the links turn blue takes about 1 second
- scrolling the notebook is awful when you hover your mouse over one the time-series entries
- clicking the small arrow at the lower left to display the next 20 entries takes several seconds
- any editing in the notebook has a lag and particularly selecting something with the mouse becomes impossible
- resizing the window takes considerable more time

During some of these actions, I see the small "Progress Dialog" popping up.

Having said all that, we get an idea what exactly is the bottle-neck: front end rendering. So here is an example of 10x20 time-series placed in a dataset. This highlights the issue and I needed to delete the output cell just to copy the code here:

```
v = {2, 1, 6, 5, 7, 4};
t = {1, 2, 5, 10, 12, 15};
ts = TimeSeries[v, {t}];
Dataset[ConstantArray[
  Association @@ Table["Key" <> ToString[i] -> ts, {i, 10}]
  , 20]
 ]
```

Maybe some folks can try to reproduce the issue with the examples I've given.

### Details

I will report this issue once more. I came up with the following demonstration, where we first create a dataset without showing it

```
head = CharacterRange["A", "E"];
ip[] := ListInterpolation /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {Length[head], 10}];
ds = Dataset@Table[Inner[Rule, head, ip[], Association], {40}];
```

This takes about 0.01 seconds on my machine. Next, we look at the `OutputForm` of `ds`. Noteworthy, it is instantaneous although it shows the entire dataset. Furthermore, the front end is as fast as it should be

```
OutputForm[ds]
```

Next, we let the front end render the dataset in all its beauty

```
ds
```

This takes over 10 seconds, pops up a "Progress Dialog" and the front end is mostly unresponsive afterward.

**Note**: For me, it makes a difference if my notebook is fullscreen or not. If I have a notebook of normal size, where the dataset is cropped, it is much slower than in fullscreen, where the entire dataset is visible. Weird.

Comment: Just for completeness: The issues described in the original question and your answer also occur with the Windows frontend.

Comment: I had no chance to test on Windows and I wasn't sure if it really showed up to that degree for the "flagship operating system". But thanks for testing!

Comment: @halirutan: This is nearly the dataset I used (Data for Johns Hopkins, CSV transformed to `TimeSeries) ;-)

Comment: You can also see this issue with `ResourceData["Sample Data: Boston Homes"]`. Read it out once or twice in your frontend and watch the whole thing break.

Comment: Yes I have the same issue on my Windows system. I also notice that the CPU utilization is up to 40% when rendering and the GPU is at 0%. Not sure if it means anything but just an observation

Comment: Just a reminder that `Query[]` can be used on list of associations with good performance. I use `Dataset` the same way I use `TraditionalForm`: only for a final nice rendering when needed.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino I never use `Dataset`. It's never been the most performant and I just don't need all this nice rendering during work. A list of associations is exactly what I use in almost all cases.

Comment: Is `Dataset` merely a formatting thing?  Or does it to more than that?

Comment: This all works tremendously fast on 12.0.0. I have no slowdown at present. So I can not test.

Comment: @QuantumDot, mostly formatting. There's some internal type state maintained in `Dataset` and it's syntactically easier to compose `Query` like this `ds[query1][query2]` vs if the underlying data are (possibly nested) `Lists` or `Associations`, which need the explicit syntax `as // Query[query1] /* Query[query2]`. But `Dataset` doesn't maintain indexing in the way that python pandas does.

Answer (score 27):

Dataset was restructured in the 12.1 release in order to support expanded formatting options and interactivity such as hiding and sorting. As a result, some Dataset outputs showed a slowdown due to inefficiencies in the dynamic output structures they produce.

Because the code of Dataset is automatically field upgradable, we have released an update to its paclet that should fix those issues. Part of the fix involves simplifying the formatting of TimeSeries and other "summary boxes" in Dataset output by removing "+" opener and icon.

If you have version 12.1 installed and have used it recently, Dataset has probably by now been upgraded. You can check for an upgrade by evaluating

```
Information[PacletObject["TypeSystem"]]["Version"]
(* "12.1.0.2" *)
```

A version number of 12.1.0 means the update has not yet occurred. A version number of 12.1.0.2 means that the update has been installed on your system.

If your system has not yet automatically updated, you can force an update by evaluating this:

```
PacletSiteUpdate /@ PacletSites[]
PacletInstall["TypeSystem"]
```

With this update, Dataset should be no slower than in version 12.0, and in some cases faster.

Comment: Or the simpler `PacletInstall["TypeSystem", UpdatePacletSites -> True]`. Thanks for the quick fix!

Comment: I already upgraded to 12.1.0.2 ..... better speed, but not quite. It seems Mathematica is becoming too big, it has too many things, AI and what have you.Video computing now. The new resolution great!
Maybe Wolfram should sell an ultra fast MiniMathematica without the non mathematical stuff.

Comment: in general `Dataset` is rather slow and can't be relied on for practical job: sluggish and unresponsive at most times. In comparison, `pandas` in the python world is such a relief. Hopefully, `Dataset` can be improved to a usable level as I can see many brilliant ideas behind this design and I do love Mathematica.

Comment: Hi @jose, I'm revisiting this thread after watching [your recent talk on `Dataset` improvement at WTC](https://youtu.be/KQeDCEGRjKM); the new type deducing system looks amazing! and you mentioned briefly it could be turned on for `Dataset` but I cannot find anything in v12.2. I'm just wondering if that's something available or we still need to wait. Anyway, really looking forward to the enhancement!

Comment: Thanks for asking. In the end this was not included in 12.2 because it requires more testing. Sorry about that!

Comment: Hi @jose, as v12.3 just rolled out, is the the new type system included in this version? thanks!

Comment: @sunt05, I'm afraid it is not ready yet.

Comment: thanks @Jose. anyway, I do feel the `Dataset`-related operations are much faster on v12.3: quite happy about that. looking forward to the new type system.